# In salesforce while adding text in custom label translations field the text is not translated in selected language?

Tags: visualforce, translation, translation-workbench

After Enabling the Translation workbench in salesforce I am trying to translate the custom label value to the japanese from English.But it isn't working please help me.

Also attached the screenshot of the issue .Please help[image]

Comment: The translation workbench doesn't translate the text for you. It displays your translations based on users' language settings.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `Translation Text` in `Japanese` language, instead of `English`.

Something like `こんにちは`

Now when you see any record, you will see the label has been translated to `Japanese`.